# Is Loop quantum cosmology replacing the Big Bang singularity with a big bounce?

Tags: cosmology, universe, big-bang, singularities, loop-quantum-gravity

Am I correct in understanding that in the cosmological version of Loop quantum gravity, namely Loop quantum cosmology, the universe in all models starts with a big bounce? Are there other models, for example, the pre-big bang condition with unconnected loops?

Answer (score 2):

Loop Quantum Cosmology is a finite, Symmetry reduced model of LQG, which for a layman means it arose from Loop Quantum Gravity. It predicts a Quantum bridge between the Expansion and the Contraction of the Cosmological branches. So, instead of having Big Bang, you have a Big Bounce. Loop Quantum Cosmology aims to describe a lot more than Bounce, it mathematically describes the Inflation in the Early Universe. For more, you can read the articles of Francessca Vidotto and Aurelien Barrau. The first Link is given here. https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01737503. They talk about some basic aspects of Loop Quantum Cosmology and the Loop Quantum Cosmology aspects of the Dark Universe

Comment: Are there other models, for example, the pre-big bang condition with unconnected loops?

Comment: Again your question can't be answered if you give more clarity, because it is not currently accepting answers. Please tell us for us to answer what are the conditions/models you are asking for so that we can understand what you want to say.

Comment: I'm talking about loop quantum gravity and describing the cosmology of the early universe (before the big bang) using this model.

Comment: There would not be a "before the big bang" or a "pre-big bang condition", only an initial state or something similar to it. With "the pre-big bang condition with unconnected loops?" are you referring to parallel, isolated universes, each or many of which are [cyclic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_model)? Or one universe with one initial state (or sth similar) that evolved into many parallel, isolated cyclic universes? You should probably make your question clearer.

Comment: @Arman armenpress so what are unconnected loops?? honestly, your question needs to be closed as it needs to be more focused and clear and it is not currently accepting the answers.

Comment: Not universes. And separate, separable loops.

Comment: What you exactly mean by Pre big bang condition with unconnected loops? Please be very thorough and clear, and we want few equations for a clarity, Otherwise, the question may be closed permanently.

Comment: I mean, the loops do not interact with each other, so there is no classical space-time. This is the state of non-interacting loops. But suddenly they begin to interact, form spin foam, which on large scales manifests itself as classical space-time.

Comment: I said you to give equations for describing what you are saying and you are currently asking irrelevant questions..

Comment: Arman Armenpress, all your answers are in the article I recommended you.

Comment: @SpinFoam damn I love your username